Why phonons outside the First Brillouin zone can be represented by phonons inside the First Brillouin zone?
I cannot understand clearly that why phonons outside the First Brillouin zone (in terms of wave numbers) can be represented by phonons within the First Brillouin zone.
For the 1-D monoatomic case, with a lattice constant $a$ (or interatomic distance), the reciprocal lattice constant is $\frac{2\pi}{a}$, thereby the first Brillouin zone is between $k=-\pi/a$ and $k=\pi/a$ for drawing the phonon band dispersion.
According to Figure 5, Chapter 4, Introduction to Solid State Physics (Charles Kittel),  wave-numbers ($k$) outside the first Brillouin zone, and associated atomic vibration (phonon) merely reproduce lattice motions described by values within the First Brillouin zone.
Almost equivalent yet animating image to the Figure 5 aforementioned is below, (found from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/635103)

Suppose the wave of the red line has $k_{0} = \frac{2\pi}{2a} = \frac{\pi}{a} $, and the black line has $k_{1} = \frac{\pi}{a} + \frac{2\pi}{a} = k_{0}+\frac{2\pi}{a}$.
With the spatial part of a phonon wave function, $\exp(ikx)$, the displacement of an atom is $u(x)=\exp(ikx)$.
For phonons of $k_{0}$ and $k_{1}$, and two adjacent atoms at $x=x_{0}$ and $x=x_{0}+a$,
$$
\begin{align}
k_{0} &: u(x_{0}) = \exp{(ik_{0}x_{0})}   \\
k_{0} &: u(x_{0}+a) = \exp{(ik_{0}(x_{0}+a))} = \exp{(ik_{0}x_{0})}\exp{(ik_{0}a)} \\
k_{1} &: u(x_{0}) = \exp{(ik_{1}x_{0})}  \\
k_{1} &: u(x_{0}+a) = \exp{(ik_{1}(x_{0}+a))} = \exp{(ik_{1}x_{0})}\exp{(ik_{1}a)} = \exp{(ik_{1}x_{0})}\exp{(ik_{0}a)}
\end{align}
$$
therefore, for both $k_{0}$ and $k_{1}$, $u(x_{0}+a)/u(x_{0})$ is identical as $\exp{(ik_{0}a)}$.
To me, this means that a phase difference between two adjacent atoms is identical for both phonons. But how this justifies one phonon can be represented (or identical?) by other? This feels like related to Bloch theorem, but I cannot clearly understand.
Another thought of mine is that the First Brillouin zone specifies the maximum size of phonon wave-number (or the minimum size of phonon wavelength), and phonons beyond that (having larger wave-number) cannot be formed by atoms. If so, such phonons do not exist?

Remember that phonons are a mathematical convenience to describe changes in position and momentum of the real particles composing the lattice. The same physical state is the same with both representations you chose (a phonon with $k$ inside the first zone and a phonon with a $k$ outside of the first zone), meaning that is redundant

The text, the animation, and most importantly the mathematics, prove that any wavevector outside of the 1BZ just causes double-counting mistakes. They do not actually exist, because there are no atoms in the region between two nearest-neighbour-atoms to show a difference.

You're making it more complicated than it needs to be.  What matters is the motion of the atoms. And for both of those choices, you get the same motion of the atoms. Thus, these two are really the same vibrational mode (i.e., a phonon mode).

Thank you for good comment @march  and others (naturallyInconsistent, OfekGillon).   I guess I was circling around, the key point is the discreteness of atomic arrangement. Any wave form with $k$ beyond 1BZ becomes meaningless because of that.
